# Reading Dates correctly regardless of format

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a way to read date time correctly regardless of date format (e.g. en-AU and en-US) in C# 4.0 or whatever framework version?

Below is two different date formats (top row is Australian format, bottom row is US format):

```
Timestamp,Windows User,Computer,Product,Version,Id,User,Action 
5/04/2011 9:14:16 AM,terryg,KETTSAM51,powerfulSoftware,3.0,0,Garry Terry,Lock
5/1/2011 12:38:22 PM,weanern,KETTSAM51,powerfulSoftware,3.0,1,Admin,Lock
```

What I want is to be able to read the dates, and process them all as Australian formatted dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a way you could do it, for example, how should this parse:

08/01/2010

That's a valid date in both US and AU formats, so there will always be ambiguity unless you give the parser an extra hint.

Answer (score 4):

```
string australiaCultureString = "en-AU";

CultureInfo australiaCulture = new CultureInfo(australiaCultureString);
```

To read as Australian culture:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(inputString, australiaCulture);
```

To represents Australian date time when call ToString()

```
string timeString = time.ToString(australiaCulture);
```

Comment: I know how to parse it as an Australia date gents. It's just that I was hoping that the program could determine what sort of date format it is (whether en-US or en-AU) and parse it into a Datetime object with correct day and month values.

Comment: AFAIK, By default the program will select the currently language settings used in windows, so if that was formatted in Australian format, then it will be done automatically, otherwise it is not..

Comment: @jwee:  In the general case, that's impossible, not least because some dates can be ambiguous, as illustrated in your question (5/04/2011 can be read either as April 5 or May 4).

Comment: As long as you get the correct culture settings, then you should be ok.  Now if this is user input, then you are in trouble.

Comment: @surfasb: unfortunately, it is user's error log, and they've changed regional settings. I am thinking of a better way than to use excel to change the formatting to the right one so that I can parse it correctly.

Comment: It is impossible for the program to know if these are US or AU formatted dates as they are valid for both.   Best approach is to use the standard international format if you have control over these data files:  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: Thanks guys, will modify user's data instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to know the culture when parsing a date string.

For example,

```
 DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo("en-US", false));
```

would parse the US date for you, but not the Australian date (unless both cultures happen to use the same date format, of course).